# Is there a way to group by list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data that looks like this in pandas. I want to group by value in list such that:

```
column1 column2 column3
1       14      P22
3       43      P65
4       43      141
3       14      146
5       43      P51
```

becomes:

```
column1 column2 column3
1       14      P22
3       43      P65

column1 column2 column3
4       43      141
3       14      146
5       43      P51
```

because the 141, 146 and P51 codes are all part of the same list and should be grouped that way. How can I accomplish this in pandas?

Comment: Do we have any column that defines the separation criteria? If not, define the separation criteria in another column and then group the dataframe based on that column . That should provide the answer that you are looking for .

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of [`Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)?

Comment: And how do you know they belong to the same group?

Comment: first you could create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it - and create solutions in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wjandrea mentioned in comment you can use `Series.isin(list)` to filter by list

You can create mask

```
mask = df['column3'].isin(['141', '146', 'P51'])
```

and later you can use `mask` and `~mask` to filter two different groups

```
print( df[ ~mask ] )
print( df[ mask ] )
```

---

Full working code.

I use `io.StringIO()` only to simulate file with data.
You should use `filename`

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''column1 column2 column3
1       14      P22
3       43      P65
4       43      141
3       14      146
5       43      P51
'''

import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

print(df)

mask = df['column3'].isin(['141', '146', 'P51'])
#print(mask)
print( df[ ~mask ] )
print( df[ mask ] )
```

Result:

```
   column1  column2 column3
0        1       14     P22
1        3       43     P65
2        4       43     141
3        3       14     146
4        5       43     P51
   column1  column2 column3
0        1       14     P22
1        3       43     P65
   column1  column2 column3
2        4       43     141
3        3       14     146
4        5       43     P51
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other idea is to use own `function` in `df.groupby(function)`

This function will get `row index` and it should return value which later `groupby` will use to create groups.

I used `True`, `False` because I need only two groups but if you need to create more groups then you can return some strings or values.

```
def mask(index):
    if df.iloc[index]['column3'] in ['141', '146', 'P51']:
        return True
    return False
    
for val, group in df.groupby(mask):
    print('val:', val)    
    print(group)
```

In this situation I can reduce function to

```
def mask(index):
    return df.iloc[index]['column3'] in ['141', '146', 'P51']
```

and even use `lambda`

```
for val, group in df.groupby(lambda index: df.iloc[index]['column3'] in ['141', '146', 'P51']):
    print('val:', val)    
    print(group)
```

Comment: The second solution you proposed work quite well. Thank you! I probably will need more than one group as there are multiple groupings of these codes at play. How could I return strings to dynamically map values into multiple groups?

Comment: Ah never mind I see how it works :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You should slice the original dataframe using pandas slicing syntax... assume all your original data is stored in `df`...

The first data set...

```py
>>> df[0:2]
```

The second data set...

```py
>>> df[2:6]
```